# kill -STOP shuts down

Tags: kill, shutdown, multithreading

On a 12-core Linux machine, as a user (without root privilege) I start a job on a single process. When I hit `Ctrl-Z` the process is suspended and `kill -CONT` resumes it. This works fine.

But when the same job runs with 12 threads (OpenMP), when I hit `Ctrl-Z` the machine is shut down (instant power off). The same happens sending the `kill -STOP` signal to the process.

Is it a bug of the kernel or of some driver? How can I find the origin of this problem?

Edit:
It is a 6 years old CentOS on a dual-socket (2x6-cores) without hyperthreading:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 26
06:52:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

/proc/cpuinfo

processor       : 11
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5680  @ 3.33GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 19
cpu MHz         : 1596.000
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 6
core id         : 10
cpu cores       : 6
apicid          : 52
initial apicid  : 52
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca
cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx
pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology
nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2
ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm ida arat
epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 6649.68
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Edit to answer questions in comments:

- It is 100 % reproducible. It started after an update of CentOS and moving physically the machine from one room to another 1 month ago.
- It happens immediately, there is no delay. SIGKILL works fine.
- It is a computing & I/O process.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : Instant poweroff. No trace in any log file.

Comment: Is this limited to one specific application running with exactly 12 threads, or does it hold true for any OpenMP program running with any number of threads?

Comment: Looks more like a hardware/firmware issue. Linux doesn't power down in case of panic/bug. Is it 100% reproducible?

Comment: Does it happen only on SIGSTOP? What about on SIGTERM or SIGKILL? Could it be related to CPU frequency scaling? Does it happen immediately or after a slight delay?

Comment: Can you run a `head  /proc/"$pid"/task/*/stack` to see if any of the threads are in any system call that could give  us a clue as to the source of the problem? Is that application doing computing only or does it interact with anything?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : I don't have access right now to the machine. I'll post the `head /proc/"$pid"/task/*/stack` later.